# Can't catch Exception (GLS FAILED WITH STATUS 20)

Tags: android, exception, gps, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to geolocate a lat,long pair.  When there is no exception it works great.

Logcat:

```
GLS Failed With Status 20
```

The code follows:

```
//TAG GEOCODING METHOD
    public Address getAddressForLocation(Context context, Location location) throws IOException {

     Address a = null;
     try{
        if (location == null) {
            a=null;
        }
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        int maxResults = 1;


        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, maxResults);


        if (addresses.size() == 1) {
            a=addresses.get(0);
        } else {
            a=null;
        }
     }catch (Exception e){
      Log.w("EXCEPTON!", "Exception Caught in geocode");
      a=null;
     }
     return a;
    }
```

The call is also wrapped in a try/catch block.

```
 @Override//TAG On Location Changed
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
//SET ALL VALUES
            dlat = arg0.getLatitude();
            dlon = arg0.getLongitude();

            delev = arg0.getAltitude() * 3.2808399;
            delev = round(delev, 2);

//GET THE ADDRESS
              try {
                addy = getAddressForLocation(this,arg0);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }
                _lastaddy = _addy;
                //DISPLAY ALL INFORMATION
                 _addy = addy.getAddressLine(0);  
                    LONGBOX.setText(String.valueOf(dlon));
                   LATBOX.setText(String.valueOf(dlat));
if(_addy!=_lastaddy){
                      ADDRESS.setText(_addy);
}

                  }
```

The rest of the logcat is below.  Any help with this would be GREAT.  I can not catch this exception and have stared at this code so long and still dont know what I have done wrong.

LOGCAT:

```
LocationMasfClient  reverseGeocode(): GLS failed with status 20
AndroidRuntime      Shutting down VM
dalvikvm            threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400208b0)
AndroidRunTime      FATAL EXCEPTION: main
AndroidRunTime      java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you catch the exception, but then return (and eventually try to use) a null Address object in `getAddressForLocation`

```
catch (Exception e){
      Log.w("EXCEPTON!", "Exception Caught in geocode");
      a=null;
     }
     return a;
```

So, at this point addy will be null:

```
addy = getAddressForLocation(this,arg0);
```

When you go to use addy, you will get a `NullPointerException`

```
_addy = addy.getAddressLine(0);
```

You either need to check if addy is null before you use it, or throw the `Exception` you catch in `getAddressForLocation` and handle it in `onLocationChange`

Comment: This is exactly the reason.  As obvious as that was I just could not see it.  Thank you for pointing that out to me.